# How can i make my header in excel have a value from a cell and changes according?

Tags: excel, header, worksheet

am trying to put a header in my worksheet but i want it to be the value of a cell and changes every time i change the value in the cell.

i found this code but doesnt help:

Sub headerofactivesheet()
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader = range("a1").value
End Sub

Comment: What do you mean by an "header"? If you meant freezing rows, that's covered at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/freeze-panes-to-lock-rows-and-columns-dab2ffc9-020d-4026-8121-67dd25f2508f.

Comment: i didn't freeze pane them

Comment: So what's your question? Be clear.

Comment: i want to put a header but not using the tool called header & footer, i want to use a vba code to pick the value in a cell and inserts it as a header in my worksheet

Comment: Again, what do you mean by "header"? Excel is not Word where the concept of a "header" exists. I'm quite unsure on why you want to use VBA as well.

Comment: thats what i mean by header, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/headers-and-footers-in-a-worksheet-cae2a88c-64a7-42ab-96a4-28d2fc16ad31

Comment: @IntelPower Does the vba code work with a string variable instead?

Comment: this is the code have used and it have achieved what i want                                         Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
Dim sh As Worksheet
For Each sh In Me.Worksheets
sh.PageSetup.CenterHeader = sh.Range("B1").Value & vbTab & Date
Next sh
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Would a cell formula be an ok solution?
You click on your header cell and write "=A1", where A1 is the cell that contains the text you change

Comment: i tried  that but it doesn't send the value to the location of header in excel